# Did Rantideva kill cows and cook in his kitchen to feed the hungry?

Tags: mahabharata, animals, non-vegetarian, cows

I was listening to Mahabharata audio podcasts. My doubt was when Rishi Kaushika met the butcher in Mithila nagara, did the butcher mention that king Rantideva also killed many animals including cows and later cooked them in his kitchen to feed the hungry and the needy?

Answer (score 1):

[Drona Parva](http://en.krishnakosh.org/krishna/Mahabharata_Drona_Parva_Chapter_67) says that he donates food cooked by 2000 cooks.

> Narada said, 'Rantideva, the son of Srinjaya, we hear, fell a prey to death. **That high-souled king had two hundred thousand cooks to distribute excellent food, raw and cooked, like unto Amrita, unto the Brahmanas,** by day and by night, who might come to his house as guests.

[image]

Now time to analyse the passage 
of [Vanaparva](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03207.htm).

> And, O Brahmana, king Sivi, the son of Usinara, of great forbearance attained to heaven, which is hard to reach, giving away his own flesh. And in days of yore, O Brahmana, **two thousand animals used to be killed every day** in the kitchen of king Rantideva; and in the same manner two thousand cows were killed every day; and, O best of regenerate beings, king Rantideva acquired unrivalled reputation by distributing food with meat every day.

Let's analyse the sankrit shloka.

> राज्ञो महानसे पूर्व रन्तिदेवस्‍य वै द्विज
>   द्वे सहस्रे तु **वध्‍येते** पशूनामन्‍वहं तदा
>   अहन्‍यहनि वध्‍येते द्वे सहस्रे गवां तथा
>   **समांसं** ददतो ह्रान्नं रन्तिदेवस्‍य नित्‍यशः
>   अतुला कीर्तिरभवन्‍नृप्‍स्‍य द्विजसत्तम

Here *VadhYate* is translated as *killing*. Which is against the sankrit Grammer. *VadhYate* here means *tieing*.
Similarly *Mansam* is a sankrit word which means both rice meal and meat.

- **Shatpath Brahamn 1:2:3:8**

[image]

Here, it is clearly written that rice means *Mamasa* translated as flesh. It means that he donates food not cow meat. If you translate these words as *killing* and *meat* that it will contradict the shloka given in [Anushasan Parva](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/m13b039.htm).

> He, who, without being checked by the restraints of the scriptures, sells a cow, or **kills one, or eats the flesh of a cow,** or they, who, for the sake of wealth, suffer a person to kill kine,--all these, viz., **he that kills, he that eats, and he that permits the slaughter,--rot in hell for as many years as there are hairs on the body of the cow so slain.**

[image]

Shanti Parva also prohibits cow slaughter.

[image]

You could read this [blog](https://sciencebyhinduism.wordpress.com/2017/04/30/an-unholy-dispute-on-holy-cows/) for more shlokas prohibits cow slaughter.

Comment: "Drona Parva says that he donates food cooked by 2000 cooks" - that whole chapter is missing from Critical Edition of Mahabharata.

Comment: See commentary of that chapter of Satapatha Brahmana [here](https://tinyurl.com/y8tf5cpv): 'The drift of this story is most likely that in former times all these victims had been offered. We know it for certain in the case of horses and oxen, though afterwards these sacrifices were discontinued. As to sheep and goats, they were considered proper victims to a still later time. When vegetable offerings took the place of bloody victims, **it was clearly the wish of the author of our passage to show that**, for certain sacrifices, **these rice-cakes were as efficient as the flesh of animals**.'

Comment: @sv. The passage of donating beef is also interplotation than this whole question is baseless.

Comment: @sv. The commentries are not authentic. Anyone can write anything from his own understanding. Commentries could even contradict each other.

Comment: "commentaries are not authentic" - do you have another commentary to compare with? If not, we go by the available commentary. Did you read the translation? In this case, we don't even need a commentary, the intent is very clear...it says "When it is baked, it becomes bone: for then it becomes somewhat hard; and hard is the bone." Whoever wrote it is comparing baked rice flour with bones of a real animal.

Comment: So what this implies is, unless otherwise stated "māṃsa" means meat i.e., flesh of an animal. In this special case, it has to be interpreted as rice cake because the ritual itself is offering an alternative to animal sacrifice.

Comment: @sv. I could quote many commentries from Arya samaji works. If you have a confusion regarding Shatpath brahman than for your kind information VS Apte dictionary also gives to meaning of mamsa. One meat and second fruit. Third curd and rice.

Comment: Like I said, the context is important, using a meaning from Satapatha Brahmana and applying to a verse in Mahabharata is not a good way to interpret scriptures.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107046/discussion-between-sanatan-darshan-and-sv).